# PHP form to update string, always returns success

Tags: php, sql, forms

I am trying to use a php form to update a sql database.

After spending hours i am finally able to update the database but the trouble is even if the row is not found matching the string, it still returns the message "updated data successfully". I checked the database and there is no other enteries that have been entered but I really want to make the user aware when they mistype the id.

Thanks

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'user';
    $dbpass = 'password';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if (! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $UniqueID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UniqueID']);
    $Referral = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Referral']);

    mysql_select_db('database');

    $sql = "UPDATE tablename set Referral = '$Referral' WHERE ID = '$UniqueID'"; 

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    }

   mysql_close($conn);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you should be using `mysqli` instead.

Comment: @CodeGodie Especially as the mysql extension is removed in PHP 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because an update which doesn't change any rows is **NOT** a failure. It's simply a query which changed/found/affected no rows.

You need to check [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) instead.

e.g.

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
if ($result === false) {
    die(mysql_error()); // something blew up completely
} else if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0) {
    ... nothing was changed
}
```

A failure in sql is due to syntax errors, communications errors, or "meta" errors like violating constraints. An empty result set is a perfectly valid result set that just happens to be empty.

Comment: Thanks, stumbled across another thread that had this suggestions minutes after posting this. didnt find it for hours before. Apologize for the similar posts

Answer (score -1):

You can check if any error has occured after `$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );` by doing

`if (mysql_error()) print 'Update Failed, Incorrect id';`